# Powershell close file to rename as last step in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm struggling to rename the current file as the last step in a foreach loop (which processes all .csv files in a directory in turn) before starting to process the next file.

```
$rootpath = "C:\Somewhere\Working\"
$List = get-childitem $rootpath | where {$_.extension -eq ".csv"}
foreach($file in $List){
  foreach($Computer in (Import-CSV $rootpath\$file -Header Assett,Group,Location))
    {
    New-ADComputer -Name $Computer.Assett
    }
  Rename-Item $rootpath\$_ -NewName ($rootpath + "\" + $_.BaseName + '.bak')

                       }
```

Returns the error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename the item at 'C:\Somewhere\Working\' because it is in use.
```

Simply renaming all csv files after the foreach loop has completed, using the following, works as expected but leaves the risk that another input file may have been created since the script started and gets renamed without being processed.

```
get-childitem -path $rootpath | where {$_.extension -eq ".csv"} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + '.bak'}
```

I'd appreciate clues how to close the file so that I can perform the rename within the loop - or a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$rootpath = "C:\Somewhere\Working\"

# Get all csv files (filter is quicker than filtering all files using where)
get-childitem $rootpath -filter "*.csv" | % {

  # import the csv (closes the file)
  $csv = Import-CSV -Path $_ -Header Assett,Group,Location

  # loop around file contents
  foreach($Computer in $csv)
  {
    New-ADComputer -Name $Computer.Assett
  }

  # rename the file
  Rename-Item $_ -NewName $_.BaseName + '.bak'

}
```

Comment: @user3168914 Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer was helpful to you, be sure to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left.